# Remove records without reloading the page with AJAX

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, record, delete-record

When I delete a record from database by Ajax I think you should try reloading the page until the page is deleted Is there a way to solve this problem, there

this is the jquery code

```
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
    $('#del>a').click(function(){

    $.post(
        'ajax.php',
        { delid:$(this).next('input').val() },
        function(data)
        {
            $('#result').html(data);
        })

    })
});
```

this is the php code

```
if(isset($_POST['delid']))
{
    $id = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['delid']);
    $admin->DeleteItem($id,'news');
}
```

Comment: So what exactly is your question?
You want to issue an AJAX request, and reload the page until the server returns a 404 error? In that case... why use AJAX in the first place?

Comment: Good Question, whats your problem? Is the problem that the record is still shown in the HTML page and you want to delete it?

Comment: When the record was deleted was still displayed on the page until the page was refreshed. 
Once I delete records without having to refresh the page manually after the removal

Answer (score 1):

```
if(isset($_POST['delid']))
{
    $id = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['delid']);
    $del = $admin->DeleteItem($id,'news');
    if($del)
     {
       echo "deleted";
      }

}
```

not `function(data)` its  `success:  function(data)`

```
    success:  function(data) {
    if(data=="deleted")
    {
     $(this).hide();
     }
     },
```